# Mule mvn studio:studio making invalid JAR files in .classpath reference

Tags: maven, plugins, mule

when I run:

```
mvn studio:studio
```

In my Maven Mule studio, what the Maven Mule Plugin will produce is .classpath file.

There are two wrong entries in that classpath file:

```
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/cglib-nodep/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/jboss/jboss-jee/4.2.0.GA/jboss-jee-4.2.0.GA.jar"/>
```

For the first entry, the folder is wrong, it should be not "M2_REPO/cglib-nodep/cglib-nodep/2.1_3..." the correct entry would be: "M2_REPO/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.1_3"

And for the other classpath entry the JAR is wrong, it is not "jboss-jee" it is "jboss-j2ee".

I do not have any of those jars in my pom.xml this is something the Maven Mule plugin seems to automatically generate into the .classpath file.

Is this a bug in the plugin ?

What can I do as a workaround ?